# linked reports in ssrs not returning data

Tags: reporting-services

I am adding a new parameter to a report that is suppose to parse to a linked report

In the new report the same parameter will be created to retreive data on that report.

The general data set is a code but tyhe parametr datasource is a cube.so there is no drop down list to choose parameter.How do I parse the value.Will just selecting the parameter on tyhe fx  tab do tyhe job?

I tried =Fields(Parameters!EA.Value).Value
it is giving me an error.
i TRIED =Parameters!EA.Value
It is returning 0 values on lnked report

Comment: Your question has so many lazy typos - perhaps that is the issue with your code?

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have to allow a default value on the parameter of null, so the report will run.